# How to programmatically determine the state/structure of an SQL Server trigger via SQL itself?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, triggers, sql-server-2016, liquibase

The company I work for has a product that makes use of SQL Server 2016, with 2008 as an absolute functional minimum, and uses Liquibase to push updates to that database.

There is a trigger on a table that was not created correctly in the first place, and needs to have a full replacement where the main SQL is quite different than the original.

Because of the re-run nature of Liquibase, I need to create a “precondition” to determine if the trigger is in an original state or in a rewritten state. Without that ability to create a precondition that can check the functional structure of the trigger, Liquibase will just run the trigger-replacement script each and every time the overall product (which uses the DB) is launched. Which will be each and every work day, if not several times a day, for every workstation that the product is installed on. Which could easily be a dozen or more in any one client’s office.

As well, an analysis of production databases in the wild has shown that creation <-> update values on the `sys.triggers` table are not reliable for this purpose. I cannot compare the two to see if they are the same (go ahead and update) or different (the new trigger is in play), because for some clients that old trigger was “updated” *after* the client moved to our product, but the trigger isn’t yet in the new required format. And new clients being stood up will move through all pre-Liquibase DB updates *first,* which *may* also include prior updates to that trigger, also screwing up the `sys.triggres` date values.

About the only thing I can think of is to come up with a new name for the rewritten trigger (oldName_v2 for example), and run a precondition on the existence of the old trigger with its name to have it pre-emptively deleted.

I am just punting this out here in case someone has a method by which I could use SQL (within Liquibase’s precondition check) to determine the structure of the trigger, such that a go/no-go can be made on the updating of the trigger itself.

Comment: You can check sys.sql_modules.definition column for the trigger if it fulfills whatever code you need it to have

Comment: A new name is probably easiest, but you can use `sys.sql_modules` as mentioned.

Comment: sys.sql_modules: created_date = modify_date ?

Comment: True? Triggerhas in this case the src code changed

Comment: Yes Bogdan, but not sure it's the change he's looking for. I think searching for actual code is better

Comment: Doesn't Liquibase have a `DATABASECHANGELOG` table? Couldn't you just query that in your precondition to see if you need to execute the changeset?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning - the problem is that this project only recently started using Liquibase, and all of the initial setup and about 80% of all updates are conducted using pre-Liquibase migrations.